# How to listen for custom events defined web component

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have a custom element `my-checkbox` that wraps a checkbox, label, styling, etc.  When that checkbox is toggled I am defining a `CustomEvent` named check within my constructor, like so:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
   this.checkEvent = new CustomEvent("check", {
     bubbles: true,
     cancelable: false,
   });
 }
```

I dispatch that event when the checkbox is toggled:

```
toggleCheckbox(){
  this.dispatchEvent(this.checkEvent);
  console.log(this.checkEvent);
  ...
}
```

I infer that this event is being dispatched because the contents of the console.log show the signature of a CustomEvent

I have another custom element `my-checkreport` that contains my-checkbox and is supposed to react to the "check" event.  I have defined an event listener in the connected callback of `my-checkreport`

```
connectedCallback(){
  ...
  this.addEventListener("check", function (e) {
        console.log('listend to check event');
        console.log(e);
    });
 }
```

However, this eventListener never fires, never seems to 'hear' the "check" event dispatched in the `my-checkbox` component.  I've tried adding this listener in the constructor with the same result.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Background: I'm doing it this way in the interest of making these elements composable.  I also have read that best practices for developing web components is to "Use custom events to pass information out of components..."

Comment: Seems to work for me in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EWerge?editors=1011). Can you provide a codepen that models your scenario?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your compound element `<my-checkreport>` uses a Shadow DOM to embed its content (`<my-checkbox>`, label, styling...), dispatched events from an inner element (here `<my-checkbox>`) will be fired inside the (container's) Shadow DOM.

Therefore, you should add the event listener to the Shadow DOM's root of the compound custom element (`this.shadowRoot`) instead of to the element (`this`) itself. In `<my-checkreport>`:

```
connectedCallback(){
  ...
  this.shadowRoot.addEventListener("check", function (e) {
        console.log('listend to check event');
        console.log(e);
    });
 }
```

More on Shadow DOM:

- For the beginners: [Presentation by Eric Bidelman](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom)
- Good summary: [Synthesis by Hayato Ito](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/)
- Specs: [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)
- SO: [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow-dom?filter=all&sort=active)

Comment: Clearly I have more to read up on about shadow root.  Any suggestions?  The mdn article is a little spartan - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot

Comment: @tim I've added a few links in my answer: the first 2 cover what you need to know.

Comment: See Clayton's other answer for the more updated answer of emitting/listening out of the shadowroot via composed

Comment: @SeanKPS, the *composed* event has some drawbacks. The *check* event could be caught somewhere in the page and never reach the immediate container. In the present OP use case it is safer to let the event confined in its Shadow DOM.

Comment: True, I suppose I didn't see OP mention that the listening component was inside the shadow root of the other. It doesn't seem specified. Either way we have answers here that apply to both scenarios.

Comment: What if it doesn't use Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 38):

For others who end up here, the specific property you're looking for to break out of the shadow root 'jail' is "composed".

So:

```
this.checkEvent = new CustomEvent("check", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: false,
  composed: true
});
```

You can also add another property, "detail" which will carry custom data on the event, if you like.

More info here: [composed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed)

Comment: would it be right to say that using bubbles: false would set it to capture instead?

Comment: Another thing to watch out for when dealing with events, and this is a silly bug but can bite you if you're not careful, make sure you dispatch with "this" i.e. this.dispatchEvent(my_custom_event); - I've inadvertently done dispatchEvent(some_event) - the code works fine, but your listener never fires. That's because without "this", you're dispatching the event from the window object, essentially doing window.dispatchEvent(some_event).

Comment: @ClaytonGulick That's no silly bug, that's the fun of JavaScript :-). Unlike C# or Java, `this` is required when you want to access instance functions. `dispatchEvent()` is a function inherited from base classes like `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I'm a little late to this party but wanted to confirm that adding "this" to the dispatchEvent call is what solved my problem. Thank you for adding the comment about that!